PKI architecture "redundancy": Online root & 1 Sub CA?
My company prefers minimalism and "KISS" over best practice. I've read the documentation, and know that "offline root CAs" are best practice. A need has arisen to add redundancy to our already existing online enterprise-CA (Microsoft AD integrated), which is a root CA. As I understand it, certificates issued in a well configured 2 tier PKI are redundant by virtue of the clients checking many URLs for the CAs (no load balancing required).
Question: In our context, would it be sufficient to spin up a sub CA and continue allowing either the root or the sub CA to issue certificates to endpoints?

Adding additional CAs doesn't really give you redundancy.  While you may gain some redundancy when issuing - the subscriber can potentially choose either CA - it gives no redundancy when it comes to certificate verification by the relying party, as each CA will be using its own private key, its own Subject, and its own CA database. To the relying parties, they are completely different CAs.
Certificate verification generally happens far more often than issuance, so this is where redundancy would be important.
Signing a subordinate CA with the current CA doesn't help verification.  If the current CA fails, it cannot provide verification information to the relying parties, even if the subordinate CA is online. Certificates issued by the subordinate CA will therefore fail verification as the original CA is part of the chain.
However, in the scenario where the subordinate CA fails, certificates issued by the original CA will still be verifiable by relying parties, but that's only the same as your current situation.
The assumption above is that your company's minimalist/KISS principles haven't stooped so low as to disable certificate verification!
The only option you have is to use a failover cluster.  This would help if the CA host failed, as the alternative server in the cluster would take over.  But it doesn't help if the CA database is corrupted somehow as the alternative server would end up using the same corrupted database.
If you want real redundancy, ditch Microsoft ADCS.

Help me get this straight then please - because the "best practice" is to:

Create a stand-alone offline CA
Optionally create 1 or more intermediary CAs (unclear to me if online/offline standalone/enterprise)
Create many online "enterprise/active directory integrated" sub ca's.

If that's the best practice, are you saying that a cert signed by subA cannot be verified by subB if subA is offline? The only way what you're saying in your post makes sense is if what I'm saying here is also true.

Correct, subA has nothing to do with subB other than they are signed by the same superior CA.  The Certificate Revocation List (CRL), which is a method to pass revocation information, has to be signed by the certificate issuer.  Therefore subA and subB must have their own CRL and cannot sign on behalf of the other (ignoring the fact that they have different database of issued certs).  The alternative Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP) can be a little more flexible in a fully Microsoft environment, but Microsoft's OCSP server uses CRLs as their database, which negates that advantage.
